# how to get rid of html tags from a list in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping. This is the  [link](https://nepal.globalbajaj.com/en/brands/pulsar/pulsar-ns-200-abs) that I am working on. I extracted the needed information with this code

```
page = requests.get('https://nepal.globalbajaj.com/en/brands/pulsar/pulsar-ns-200-abs')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

specs = soup.find_all(class_='col-md-6 specification')
infos = [spec.find_all('li') for spec in specs] 

print(infos)
```

I get the results in this form:

```
[[<li>Type: 4-Stroke - Liquid Cooled, Digital Triple Spark</li>, <li>Max Power: 23.5 @ 9500 (Ps @ RPM)</li>, <li>Max Torque: 18.3 @ 8000 (Nm @ RPM)</li>, <li>Displacement: 199.5 cc</li>, <li>Brake Size Front:  
                                                                        300 mm Disc</li>, <li>Brake Size Rear:  100/80 - 17,52 P Tubeless</li>, <li>Tyre Front:  230mm</li>, <li>Tyre Rear:  130/70 - 17,62 P Tubeless</li>, <li>Brake Type Front:  Hydraulic disc brake with Single channel ABS, Disc diameter 300 ...
```

It shows error when i use

```
infos = [spec.find_all('li').get_text() for spec in specs]
```

How can I remove those list tags and only get texts ?

Comment: It does not look like a duplicate of the given marked question.

Comment: You have nested list so used - `[[item.text for item in spec.find_all('li')] for spec in specs]`